# how to stop old pact files being merged with new ones, without having to rely on my colleagues knowing to clean the target/pacts folder?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, pact

[Pact merges pacts at the file level](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/471), this is great for merging pacts from multiple tests, but not so great when you want to modify and re-run a test without cleaning the target/pacts folder.

The default junit run config in intellij doesn't clean the target folder before running the tests; I know I can use maven clean/remove the files manually, but this means anyone else who runs these tests locally *needs to know to run them a specific way*.

I want to merge pacts from multiple tests so I don't want to turn off merging.
I tried implementing a before method that deletes files from the pact folder if they exist, but it was janky.

I'm considering setting the pact folder to a temporary directory that removes itself after the tests are run, but that might interfere with pushing new pacts to the broker, and I don't want to remove the folder too soon/often and end up with missing pacts. Also it's useful to be able to see the files at the end, so auto-removing them isn't ideal.

Is there a nice way to stop old pacts merging with new ones, without relying on people to *just know* they need to remove old pact files before running a modified test?

Comment: From my point of view it sounds as your tests are not made to be running over and over again. I would reconsider this idea otherwise you will not be able to rerun your tests from your IDE which is usually a bad idea...and it violates the idea of unit tests...

Answer (score 0):

Why is it an actual problem for you? As in, yes, the pact file is temporarily bigger than it should be, but what is the actual impact?

You shouldn't be publishing from your local machine anyway, that is a CI concern (I usually restrict by not providing write credentials to local environments) so if all you need is to be able to rerun a unit test then I wouldn't worry.

Alternatively, if you are all using the same IDE you could create an IDE specific config and check it in to the repo that cleans the dir before any target / test is run.

Comment: the direct impact is that no one I work with wants to write pacts because it has a rep for being confusing. Your introduction to pact is generally writing a consumer using the DSL, if you don't know to clean your pact folder and you just mess around with the DSL to see what kind of files are generated, you'll end up with a messed up file and you'll get very confused.

Comment: ex1: I create a pact with array `X`, when it should be a string. I change it without cleaning the pact folder. `X` array is not overwritten by `X` string, so the pact file continues to only contain the array. 

ex2: I create 2 pacts with states `A` and `B`, but the test is not correctly written so only the final pact is successfully written to file. I write test A first, creating a file. no clean. When I run tests A and B together, the resulting file contains both pacts, validation tests pass. When the CI job runs the tests with a clean target, the resulting pact only contains state `B`.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but the pact file is simply an artifact of the test. You share care about the test itself and not the side effect of the file being generated. It's like looking at the resulting byte code instead of the Java source which for all intents and purposes is the thing of value. This being said, I'd still like to know if there is another way. How would you expect it to work?